# Is allowing all packets on INPUT and OUTPUT on lan interface secure on a gateway router (iptables)

Tags: iptables, firewall, router

My main gateway router (Also the DHCP and DNS server for my LAN) lets me ssh in and configure iptables. Seeing as almost daily I'm making it provide more services like NTP, DNS, FTP e.c.t, I want to allow all traffic and ports on my LAN interface/subnet to and from my router to make sure these services are accessible by any device on my LAN.

Essentially disabling my LAN side firewall.

However, as this is also my gateway router I do not want to configure these iptables in a way that would allow internet traffic to exploit my iptables configuration.

**My private IP range is 192.168.50.0/24 and is automatically assigned an interface of br0.**

here are the iptables commands I used to allow all LAN traffic.

```
iptables --append INPUT --in-interface br0 --jump ACCEPT
iptables --append INPUT --source 192.168.50.0/24 --jump ACCEPT
iptables --append OUTPUT --out-interface br0 --jump ACCEPT
iptables --append OUTPUT --source 192.168.50.0/24 --jump ACCEPT
```

I'm no expert in routing or iptables but when I interpret it as '*Accept all output in 192.168.50.0/24*' it makes me think that after traffic from the internet is routed through my gateway, that all of it accepted to anywhere in my LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a brief explanation of iptables firewall:

```
INPUT will allow or deny traffic destined to the gateway/firewall host
OUTPUT will allow or deny traffic leaving the gateway/firewall host
FORWARD will allow or deny traffic going through the gateway/firewall host
```

In your case, you need to `FORWARD 192.168.50.0/24`, enable masquerade, allow return related traffic, and finally drop everything.
Assuming that `br0` interface is directly attached the local network (LAN) while `br1` is facing the internet (WAN)

Enable routing on the Linux gateway/firewall

```
$ sudo echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Forward only the LAN subnet `192.168.50.0/24` to the internet

```
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o br1 -s 192.168.50.0/24 -j ACCEPT
```

Enable masquerading (NAT)

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o br1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Allow return traffic from WAN to LAN

```
$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i br1 -o br0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```